# Can A-Frame handle collision data with <a-collada>?

Tags: collision-detection, collision, aframe, physics-engine

I know that using donmccurdy's [A-Frame Physics](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-physics-system), I can have distinct bodies collide with each other.

I'm creating a scenery in SketchUp and dropping it in via <a-collada>. Is there any way for the A-Frame Physics to generate collision data based on the model I have done in SketchUp?

Even better, is there a way I can feed it my own collision layer that I make separately, as you would see in game engines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`static-body="shape:mesh"`

"Mesh" is deprecated, but it suits my purposes, and I'm using an older version of A-Frame anyway.